# How to parse { ; } and extract the number in first position?

Tags: r

Reproducible, subset of my data:

```
owed <- c("{7; 125.04}, {203; 125.04}, {90; 125.04}", "{45; 50.72}, {355; 50.72}", "#N/A")
uuid <- c(1, 2, 3)
data <- data.frame(uuid, owed)
```

Column *owed* shows how many times each *uuid* has had a debt in the following structure **{number of in debt days; amount owed}**. There's no max limit how many times each *uuid* has had debts - some *uuids* have 80+ occasions.

I'd like to have a third column *avg_debt_days* that calculates the average in debt days for each *uuid*.
In this example the result should be the 100, 200, #N/A for *uuid* 1, 2, 3 respectively.

Considering I have 100k rows of data, can anyone suggest a method to transform and calculate this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested `sapply` and `strsplit` calls to build up a simple function that is fully vectorized:

```r
get_days      <- function(x) suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub(" |[{]|[}]", "", x)))[1]
get_mean_days <- function(x) mean(sapply(strsplit(x, ";"), get_days))
days_in_debt  <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ", "), get_mean_days)
```

So now you can just do:

```
days_in_debt(data$owed)
#> [1] 100 200  NA
```